# Replace List item with another of own choice

Tags: c#, list

have a list containing messages .I want when list contain a message like

`HelloHelloHello` , it should display `HELLO HELLO HELLO`

I have tried it. from here as well .I got

```
result.MessageList.Select<string,string>(s => s == "HelloHelloHello" ? "Hello Hello Hello" : s).ToList();
```

But it is not working for me.Help.

Comment: How do you output/check the result?

Comment: result.MessageList is comming from DB.

Comment: I meant the result of your `Select` invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you will get only one output then:

```
result.MessageList.Select<string,string>(s => s == "HelloHelloHello" ? "Hello Hello Hello" : s).ToList()[0];
```

will work.
Your current result must be

```
System.Generic.... etc
```

**EDIT**

```
        List<String> MessageList = new List<string>();
        MessageList.Add("HelloHelloHello");
        MessageList.Add("Hello1Hello1Hello1");
        MessageList.Add("Hello1Hello1Hello1");
        MessageList.Add("Hello1Hello1Hello1");
        MessageList.Add("HelloHelloHello");

        MessageList.Add("HelloHelloHello");

        List<String> output =  MessageList.Select<string, string>(s => s == "HelloHelloHello" ? "Hello Hello Hello" : s).ToList();

        foreach (String str in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

This is working, I have tested it in Console.

Comment: I can have multiple messages.

Answer (score 1):

[`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *returns* the modified enumeration as a list. The original list `result.MessageList` is not changed.

To see the updated results, you will have to do one of the following:

- Assign the return value of `ToList` back to `result.MessageList`.
- Do not use LINQ, but iterate over `result.MessageList` with a loop and modifiy the respective items right there.